# first occurence of entries in table ( access )

Tags: sql, ms-access

here is my table:

```
ID      NAME        FAMILY_ID       HASKIDS     ISPARENT
--------------------------------------------------------
1       John        1               1           1
2       Bill        1               1           0
3       Dick        1               1           0
4       Jane        2               1           1
5       Mary        2               1           0
6       Pete        3               0           1
7       Jess        3               0           1
```

and i want the result to be

```
NAME        FAMILY_ID
---------------------
Bill        1
Mary        2
```

the logic is : from each family which has kids, show the name of their first born ( highest id of each non parent member ) and corresponding family id.

so here is my first query, **query1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT family_id
FROM families
WHERE (haskids=1)
ORDER BY family_id;
```

this brings as result ( correctly ):

```
1
2
```

my second query is, **query2**:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, family_id
FROM families
WHERE family_id IN (SELECT family_id FROM query1) AND isparent=0
ORDER BY id;
```

which has the undesired result:

```
NAME        FAMILY_ID
---------------------
Bill        1
```

Because top 1 doesn't bring the top 1 from each sub-result, but the overall smaller entry id.

I'm sure i'm missing something and there's a simple way to achieve this, but i can't figure out how.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you using Access in pass-through mode to SQL Server?  If so, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: just ms access nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   id in
        (
        select  min(id)
        from    YourTable
        where   isparent = 0
        group by
                family_id
        )
```